# why is my opencv error even though i am following from geeksforgeeks

Tags: python, opencv

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("beach.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
cv2.imshow("C:\\Users\\farha\\Downloads\\WALLPAPER\\beach.jpg", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

*Error:  cv2.imshow("C:\Users\farha\Downloads\WALLPAPER\beach.jpg", image)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'*

Comment: you should use full path in `imread()`, not in `imshow()`. You could also check what you have in `image`. When `cv2` can't read image then it doesn't raise error but it returns `None` and later you may get error in other lines when you try to use this `None` to display (or change color, or edit image)

Comment: if you follow some tutorial then you could add link for this tutorial - and add it in question, not in comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `cv2` can't read image then it doesn't raise error but it returns `None` and later it may gives error in other lines when it tries to use this `None` to display image (or change color, or edit image)

You should use full path in `imread()` - `imshow` needs text for widow's title, it doesn't have to be path to image.

```
image = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\farha\\Downloads\\WALLPAPER\\beach.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

if image is None: 
    print("I can't read image")
else:
    cv2.imshow("My Image", image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: question is a duplicate. vote to close, don't answer.